# How to create a simplest web server in android?

Tags: android, webserver

Hi everyone I need some guidelines to make an application which behaves some thing like a web server.

The basic idea is you run that app on your android mobile.and that will present you an ip address (current ip of the mobile device).

Then on another system (Internet browser) you enter the IP address provided by android app, it will show a simple web page.

This web page will contain few links. If you click any of the link a text will be displayed accordingly. (The app running should get notified about the link clicked and then app will send back a text based on the link pressed, and that text will be displayed in the browser)

That's it nothing much more than that is required, I don't want any complex calculation or script executions to embed a complete web server.

or some how through socket programming to listen to for a specific url request  and based on url name i can send back simple html.

Comment: What's your specific problem? If you want rough structure: 1) Learn  java on android sockets. 2) the http standard. 3) some basic html.

Comment: Is suggest looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Like the poster above me said, what's your specific problem?

Comment: Well In case of socket programming i know i have to create a server based application which will accept the connection then we need a client code which connects to sepcific ip and port, but as i have mentioned at one side is android application and on other side there is a simple webpage (This is where I am confused)

Comment: A webserver is just a server which listens on port 80 and reacts to requests. If just one static request/response is required, I guess you can just hardcode the html request/response string and send it over your socket. Otherwise look for webserver implementations for java/android.

Comment: Please see this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358190/how-to-host-rest-api-server-in-android-application-using-jersey/59379434#59379434](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358190/how-to-host-rest-api-server-in-android-application-using-jersey/59379434#59379434) This worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) is a full-fledged web server within a single java class. You'll be up and running in minutes.

Comment: Thanks mate i will check it out and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much it work for me, At start i was bit reluctant to embed a web server in my android app, but as you said it just a class, a simple one. I am happy to use it thank you so much.

Comment: Sure thing. This piece of software has saved me weeks of development.

Comment: which class exactly holds the server, I'm a bit confused. thanks!

Comment: You can follow the documentation and best ask your question on NanoHttpd's site.